# PHP URL parameters append return special character

Tags: php, special-characters, urlencode

I'm programming a function to build an URL, here it is :

```
public static function requestContent($p_lParameters)
{
    $sParameters = "?key=TEST&format=json&jsoncallback=none";

    foreach($p_lParameters as $sParameterName => $sParameterValue)
    {
        $sParameters .= "&$sParameterName=$sParameterValue";
    }

    echo "<span style='font-size: 16px;'>URL : http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings" . $sParameters . "</span><br />";

    $aXMLData = file_get_contents("http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings" . $sParameters);

    return json_decode($aXMLData,true);
}
```

And I am calling this function with this array list :

```
print_r() result : Array ( [region] => canada [category] => housing/sale/home )
```

But this is very strange I get an **unexpected character** (note the special character none**®**ion) :

```
http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&format=json&jsoncallback=none®ion=canada&category=housing/sale/home
```

For information I use this header :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8'); ?>
```

**EDIT :**

```
$sRequest = "http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&format=json&jsoncallback=none&region=canada&category=housing/sale/home";

echo "<span style='font-size: 16px;'>URL : " . $sRequest . "</span><br />";
```

return the exact URL with problem :

```
http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&format=json&jsoncallback=none®ion=canada&category=housing/sale/home
```

Comment: wow its taking your &reg(from region) to html for register which is &reg

Comment: Yes but there is no ; at the end....

Comment: can you check what happens when you do utf8_encode($aXMLData) .. this will encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8.

Comment: I agree thats y I am shocked.. it was still taking it as ascii value..

Comment: @Dinesh see the second test as Edit... can you explain that result?

Comment: Try this "&amp;" . $sParameterName . "=" . $sParameterValue I have a feeling that something goes wrong in the conversion somewhere there.

Comment: I print the URL actually but I wont print it, I'll use it to load URL content. The problem isn't with the functon, see the edit.

Comment: Okay, but doesn't php take the ampersand as a binary and comparison operator?

Comment: I've seen pretty weird things happen when you write php vars directly into a string. See the answer Dinesh gave, single quotes might treat the ampersand differently.

Comment: Tried single quotes, nothing. Also, the query is working (the url in variable is ok) but when printed it replace the &reg event without ;, very strange!

Comment: People get so exited about answering the question that they forget the idea is to think about correct answer.. I just got carried away..

Comment: I rarelly get my questions answered, don't know if they are too rare or complicated! hehe

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie did you check the my latest answer.. i tried and it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution and this time it will work

```
$sParameters .= "&$sParameterName=$sParameterValue";
$sParameters = htmlentities($sParameters);
```

It converts all the charset into html code.. totally forgot about this even when I regualarly use it in user input...

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you build a string

```
$sParameters = "?key=TEST&format=json&jsoncallback=none";
```

And then you're **appending** to that. So it will concatenate.
Now, the last part of a string might be & and your parameter is region.

Somehow that gets converted to the html ASCII code &reg; which causes the registered symbol to appear.